# Automation: Selenium: unable to click anchor tag

Tags: selenium, hyperlink, tags, click, anchor

I have to click anchor tag in selenium. I applied
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/app/setup')")).click();`

but its not working.

```
<li class="ant-menu-item" role="menuitem" style="padding-left: 24px;">
<span role="img" class="anticon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="17" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
    <path id="Icon_ionic-md-settings" >
</path>
</svg>
</span>
<span>
Setup
</span>
<a href="/app/setup">
</a>`enter code here`
</li>
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[contains(@href,'/app/setup') because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains(@href,'/app/setup')' is not a valid XPath expression.

Answer (score 1):

As your error indicates, the xpath you specified is invalid. You are missing a closing bracket for `contains`.
You have

```
"//a[contains(@href,'/app/setup')"
```

It should be

```
"//a[contains(@href,'/app/setup')]"
```